# Subtraction of two pandas series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have one dataframe that was retrieved by xlwings. I want to produce two results in A.OUT-B.IN and A.OUT-C.IN two columns, but it always shows NaN. There is a group of three same MO. Each MO has three different stops A, B, C. All stops have input quantity and output quantity. To calculate the A.OUT-B.IN need the same MO with A stop output quantity subtract B stop input quantity. The difference in A.OUT-C.IN is input quantity is C stop. What should I do if I get the NaN values? I try to change the two series to numeric, search google, and read pandas document still can't find a solution.

Here is the sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'MO': ['510-20200701001', '510-20200701001', '510-20200701001', '510-20200701002', '510-20200701002', '510-20200701002', '510-20200701003', '510-20200701003', '510-20200701003', '510-20200701004', '510-20200701004', '510-20200701004', '510-20200701005', '510-20200701005', '510-20200701005', '510-20200701006', '510-20200701006', '510-20200701006'], 
                   'Stop Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'Amount of Input': [21000, 22112, 22476, 12000, 12609, 12775, 15000, 15595, 15844, 600, 775, 790, 1000, 1149, 1176, 6000, 6225, 6289], 
                   'Amount of Output': [22400, 22057, 22330, 12800, 12586, 12685, 16000, 15587, 15718, 800, 775, 783, 1200, 1139, 1162, 6400 ,6225, 6278], 
                   'A.OUT-B.IN':['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 'A.OUT-C.IN': ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''] })
df.loc[df['Stop Name'] == 'B', 'A.OUT-B.IN'] = df.loc[df['Stop Name'] == 'A', 'Amount of Output'] - df.loc[df['Stop Name'] == 'B', 'Amount of Input']
df.loc[df['Stop Name'] == 'C', 'A.OUT-C.IN'] = df.loc[df['Stop Name'] == 'A', 'Amount of Output'] - df.loc[df['Stop Name'] == 'C', 'Amount of Input']
```

Here is the output

```
                     MO  Stop Name  Amount of Input Amount of Output    A.OUT-B.IN  A.OUT-C.IN
    0   510-20200701001          A            21000            22400        
    1   510-20200701001          B            22112            22057           NaN  
    2   510-20200701001          C            22476            22330                       NaN
    3   510-20200701002          A            12000            12800        
    4   510-20200701002          B            12609            12586           NaN  
    5   510-20200701002          C            12775            12685                       NaN
    6   510-20200701003          A            15000            16000        
    7   510-20200701003          B            15595            15587           NaN  
    8   510-20200701003          C            15844            15718                       NaN
    9   510-20200701004          A              600              800        
   10   510-20200701004          B              775              775           NaN  
   11   510-20200701004          C              790              783                       NaN
   12   510-20200701005          A             1000             1200        
   13   510-20200701005          B             1149             1139           NaN  
   14   510-20200701005          C             1176             1162                       NaN
   15   510-20200701006          A             6000             6400        
   16   510-20200701006          B             6225             6225           NaN  
   17   510-20200701006          C             6289             6278                       NaN
```

Here is except output

```
                     MO  Stop Name  Amount of Input Amount of Output    A.OUT-B.IN  A.OUT-C.IN
    0   510-20200701001          A            21000            22400        
    1   510-20200701001          B            22112            22057           288  
    2   510-20200701001          C            22476            22330                       -76
    3   510-20200701002          A            12000            12800        
    4   510-20200701002          B            12609            12586           191  
    5   510-20200701002          C            12775            12685                        25
    6   510-20200701003          A            15000            16000        
    7   510-20200701003          B            15595            15587           405  
    8   510-20200701003          C            15844            15718                       156
    9   510-20200701004          A              600              800        
   10   510-20200701004          B              775              775            25  
   11   510-20200701004          C              790              783                        10
   12   510-20200701005          A             1000             1200        
   13   510-20200701005          B             1149             1139            51  
   14   510-20200701005          C             1176             1162                        24
   15   510-20200701006          A             6000             6400        
   16   510-20200701006          B             6225             6225           175  
   17   510-20200701006          C             6289             6278                       111
```

Comment: put a `.to_numpy()` , eg: `df.loc[df['Stop Name'] == 'A', 'Amount of Output'].to_numpy()` and same for the to be subtracted values  ...? Since the column names are different, the keys aren't identified for pandas subtraction

Comment: @anky I tried, but it shows the TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'method'

Comment: you may be missing the parenthesis, check below answer, that's what I meant only difference `.values` are now `.to_numpy()`

Comment: @anky, thank you. I have checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do, if you know that the lengths of all the corresponding vectors will be correct then just add '.values' to your calls, as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'MO': ['510-20200701001', '510-20200701001', '510-20200701001', '510-20200701002', '510-20200701002', '510-20200701002', '510-20200701003', '510-20200701003', '510-20200701003', '510-20200701004', '510-20200701004', '510-20200701004', '510-20200701005', '510-20200701005', '510-20200701005', '510-20200701006', '510-20200701006', '510-20200701006'],
                   'Stop Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'Amount of Input': [21000, 22112, 22476, 12000, 12609, 12775, 15000, 15595, 15844, 600, 775, 790, 1000, 1149, 1176, 6000, 6225, 6289],
                   'Amount of Output': [22400, 22057, 22330, 12800, 12586, 12685, 16000, 15587, 15718, 800, 775, 783, 1200, 1139, 1162, 6400 ,6225, 6278],
                   'A.OUT-B.IN':['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 'A.OUT-C.IN': ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''] })
df.loc[df['Stop Name'] == 'B', 'A.OUT-B.IN'] = df.loc[df['Stop Name'] == 'A', 'Amount of Output'].values - df.loc[df['Stop Name'] == 'B', 'Amount of Input'].values
df.loc[df['Stop Name'] == 'C', 'A.OUT-C.IN'] = df.loc[df['Stop Name'] == 'A', 'Amount of Output'].values - df.loc[df['Stop Name'] == 'C', 'Amount of Input'].values
```

Comment: thank you very much. That is exactly what I want.

Comment: @johann Great that it solved your problem.